# Play Video in landscape Full Screen in Ionic App

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have to problem to Play video landscape full screen mode.Please help me to show video in landscape full screen.

I have use the following code to view template in Ionic.

```
<ion-view view-title="Poem" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <div class="modal transparent fullscreen-player">
          <video id="myvideo" ng-src="{{clipSrc}}" class="centerme" controls="controls" autoplay poster="{{bg}}"></video>
    </div>
</ion-view>
```

Controller code as Follows :

```
.controller('PoemDetailCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.clipSrc = '/android_asset/www/video/demo.mp4'
      $scope.bg = 'img/poems/01.png';
      var video = document.getElementById("myvideo");
      if (video.requestFullscreen) {
        video.requestFullscreen();
      } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
        video.msRequestFullscreen();
      } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        video.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
        video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
      }
})
```

I got the following output in android device

[image]

And I want to output as follows by default :

[image]

Comment: have you installed any plugin to play video file in ionic framework..other than media plugin

Comment: no i am not using any plugin here I use html5 video tag

Comment: I tried with your code to play an video file in Ionic framework.. The video itself is not playing that's why I asked are you using any plugin....can you please put your code in github

Comment: please check here https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/FullscreenVideo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building on [Anas Omar's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4369214/anas-omar) answer, here is an implementation in JavaScript of the [plugin he mentions](https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation), switching orientation lock on and off when a user interaction on an HTML element triggers a change in the fullscreen status of the document.

The variable "element" should be a reference to a DOM or jQuery or angular element in JS, which in my case is a video tag, but it could be any element that triggers a fullscreen change.

```
element.on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var isFullScreen = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;

    if (isFullScreen) {
        window.screen.unlockOrientation();
        //alert("registered entered fullscreen and unlocked the orientation");

    } else {
         window.screen.lockOrientation('portrait')
        //alert("registered exit fullscreen and locked the orientation to portrait again");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 5):

https://github.com/gbenvenuti/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation

you can use this plugin in order to force the user device to change orientation when open the video

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with ionic you can use screen rotation -> https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation

1. install plugin

   ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
   npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation
2. add plugin as provider in app.module.ts

   import { VideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/video-player/ngx';
   import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
   ...
    providers: [
       StatusBar,
       SplashScreen, VideoPlayer,ScreenOrientation,
       { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
     ],
3. import dependency on your page.ts

   import { VideoPlayer } from '@ionic-native/video-player/ngx';
   import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';
   ...
   constructor(private videoPlayer: VideoPlayer,private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) { }
   ...
    onClick(){
       // this.videoPlayer.play("src/assets/vid1.mp4");
       // /home/shoniisra/Documentos/turismoApp/src/assets/vid1.mp4
       this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);
       this.videoPlayer.play('file:///android_asset/www/assets/vid1.mp4').then(() => {
         this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);
       }).catch(err => {
         this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);
       });
     }

Answer (score -2):

```
/** with CSS *//
height:100%;
margin-left: -50%
```