# ionic video player for .ism/manifest files

Tags: azure, ionic-framework, stream, android-mediaplayer, azure-media-services

Require a video player that can play .ism/manifest files. Currently I'm using Azure Media Player.It works fine in browser but not in Mobile devices. Any other player which I can integrate with my Ionic app?

Comment: Azure Media Player should work on mobile devices as well. If you log in to https://stream.microsoft.com/en-us/ with your phone you will see it in action and it should give you idea how to integrate it.

Comment: @GeorgeTrifonov : I tried but not working on device. Can you suggest what might be wrong ?

Comment: By mobile playback you mean mobile web browser playback or native in-app playback?

Comment: @GeorgeTrifonov I have made a hybrid mobile app using ionic framework . I want to play stream(.ism/manifest) videos in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to prepare your video to android playback follow article  http://mingfeiy.com/android-hls-playback-via-azure-media-services.

You should be able to have links with following format (additional strings added after *.ism/):

For HLS v4
http://htmlsamples.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/7bbf1b9d-83c0-4745-8e3d-169479671fd6/Tears.ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl)

For HLS v3: 
http://htmlsamples.origin.mediaservices.windows.net/7bbf1b9d-83c0-4745-8e3d-169479671fd6/Tears.ism/Manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)

Opening web browser from you app with these formatted links should trigger playback.

There is ionic related question not specific to azure media services: [Play Video in landscape Full Screen in Ionic App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32247407/play-video-in-landscape-full-screen-in-ionic-app) which might help you as well